# Array.prototype.slice.call vs Array.prototype.forEach.call

Tags: javascript, nodelist

[MDN says this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) about `Array.prototype.forEach.call(nodeList, fn)`:

> Passing a host object (like a NodeList) as this to a native method
>   (such as forEach) is not guaranteed to work in all browsers and is
>   known to fail in some.

And later suggests `Array.prototype.slice.call(nodeList)` to convert the node list into an array, but doesn't give any warning about it.

**So, is it safer to use the second method (so that I can later use `forEach` on the resulting array) when trying to use `forEach` on a `nodeList`, or are they pretty much doing the same thing?**

I'm currently thinking that both are doing the same: passing a host object as `this`, to a native method.

I'd use a simple `for` loop, but I'm trying to be compliant with the new version of JSLint (plus, I think `forEach` actually looks quite pretty).

Comment: It does seem like they're being inconsistent, first warning against using array operations, then using one to convert the NodeList to an array. But the latter has become such a common idiom, any browser where it fails would be shot.

Comment: Yeah, that made me confused. So, *if* they are pretty much doing the same thing, then your statement would also apply to the first method, right?: "Any browser where it fails would be shot". And any browser where it fails would be a browser that doesn't support `forEach` natively anyway? Do you know if there's a list of browsers, somewhere, where this would fail? Sorry for the many questions, and thanks. @Knu, I think that answers my last question, if that's the only browser where it fails.

Comment: Host object have undefined behaviours.